Ошибка при включении кода yandex maps api
непонятно по какой причине выдаёт ошибку ключа GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/v3/?apikey=2f7fe304-3b93-4cbf-bf18-7def35feda0a&lang=ru_RU net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request), хотел бы понять почему это происходит

Пожалуйста, приведите пример, который вы составили в jsbin.com или codepen.io, или ссылку на страницу, где возможно воспроизвести эту ситуацию. Если код короткий, хорошо бы добавить его прямо в вопрос.
Обратите внимание, поскольку JS API 3.0 работает только с ключами, у которых заполнено поле «Ограничение по HTTP Referer», на других доменах будет ошибка. Для указанных песочниц нужно будет внести домены jsbin.com и cdpn.io в список разрешённых.

@YaSupport код html и js, которые были использованы вместе с ключом обновлённым, ошибку выдаёт всё ту же https://codepen.io/goga0000/pen/OJGEXeY

Для работы кода в выбранной вами песочнице api-ключ необходимо привязывать к домену cdpn.io, а не codepen.io. Такова особенность этой песочницы. Без должной привязки запрос API будет падать с ошибкой на этапе авторизации. А сам код в скрипте следует начинать промисом ymaps3.ready.then(() => {… , не так же, как во второй версии API ymaps.ready(function () {…
